# TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures (in karma, PhantomJS, angular-cli)

Tags: angular, jasmine, phantomjs, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to run karma tests using angular cli and PhantomJS (`ng test --code-coverage --single-run`) but am getting an error which seems to be causing 24 out of my 33 unit tests to fail. When I run the tests with Chrome as the configured browser, all of the tests pass.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0) AppService should be created FAILED
    TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures. in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js (line 5424)
    stringify@[native code]
    stringify@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:5424:28
    displayModal@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:4473:57
    createModalContent@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:4453:41
    BMS@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:7282:43
    BMSService@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:2095:25930
    _createClass@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:84475:34
    _createProviderInstance$1@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:84447:38
    resolveNgModuleDep@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:84432:42
    _createClass@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_
    ...(there was more in the stack but I cropped it)
```

In other issues people had with Karma and PhantomJS some suggested uncommenting the `polyfills.ts` file. I figured that might be related since the error seems to be coming from the polyfills bundled file so I tried running the tests with the polyfills commented out and also with them uncommented out and it didn't make a difference either way.

Here is my `karma.conf.js` file: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NYBypv

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      // require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js': ['coverage']
    },
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageReporter: { type : 'html', dir : 'coverage/', 
      reporters: [ 
        { type: 'html', subdir: 'report-html' },
        { type: 'cobertura', subdir: '.', file: 'TESTS-xunit.xml' }
      ]  
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly', 'coverage' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
  });
};
```

Comment: Try removing AngularCLI as an experiment. See if the JSON circular references go away.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I tried running the tests with the command `karma start karma.conf.js`. Unfortunately the same errors show up.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. In your `karma.conf.js` file, in the `frameworks` section, remove `@angluar/cli`, and then run your tests. Your tests will fail, but the circular reference error should no longer exist. Just an isolation experiment to try.

Comment: @RandyCasburn None of the tests run when I do that. It just says `PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.002 secs / 0 secs)`

Comment: Confirms the known issue with WebPack Angular build creating circular JSON references. You cannot use PhantomJS as your browser. End of story.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Where can I find more information about that issue?

Comment: Here is one example, I'll let you google for others. As you have found, this is a very obscure problem. You'll spend three sprints getting your tests to run on PhantomJS or you could avoid Phantom and be a productive hero at work. You choose: https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-phantomjs/issues/104

Comment: @RandyCasburn Oh ok thanks. I actually already saw that issue page but thought it wasn't related to mine because it was on mocha.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is problem of `JSON.stringify` method ([proof](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-hirearchy-fc9e6s)), not Karma/Phantom.
Temporary solution is to remove circular dependencies before running `JSON.stringify`

Comment: The error is coming from the pollyfils.bundle.ts file which is not something I have control over. That is generated by angular-cli/webpack. Also this error doesn't show up if I run it with Chrome as my browser instead of PhantomJS. I'm not sure how to examine the file when using PhantomJS but in Chrome, JSON.stringify only occurs once in that same file and it is in this function (this is not code I wrote, it was generated): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLaKNX. I don't know if polyfills.bundle.ts is generated the same way in PhantomJS vs Chrome though.